# VBA datatype mismatch

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am working with Dates as my data and I think this may be causing some issues.

```
Sub test()

    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 1 to 10

        Dim fltArr(0 to 9)
        Dim X 
        Dim Largest As Date

        For items = 3 to 12
        fltArr(items-3) = Cells(items, 6)
        Next

        X = fltArr
        Largest = Application.Large(X, counter)

    Next
End Sub
```

A mismatch Error seems to occur in the line

```
Largest = Application.Large(X, counter)
```

I think this may be due to Application.Large giving an integer instead of a Date. How could I fix this?

Comment: Could be many things. Are you sure `Cells(items, 6)` contains a valid `Date` value for all `items`? Try `fltArr(items-3) = CDate(Cells(items,6).Value)`, and/or add `Debug.Assert VarType(Cells(items,6).Value) = vbDate` inside the loop - does the loop still complete?

Comment: Large does not accept array, only ranges

Comment: @ScottCraner `?Application.Large(Array(1,2,3),1)` seems to imply otherwise though.

Comment: I am sure that Cells(items, 6) contains valid Dates for all items

Comment: Ok got a repro. Why can't you do `Largest = Application.Large(Range("F3:F12"), counter)` instead? @ScottCraner is right, the function doesn't seem to work off a declared array (why it works with an inline array is a funny question mark though) - the problem isn't the integer (VBA happily converts it to a date), it's the variant array.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve? `Largest` being overwritten at every iteration of `counter`, it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve, and why you can't work with a `Range` instead of an array... given the values are in a `Range` in the first place.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon If you declare the arrays as double then it works, it even converts it back to a date when assigning the result to `Largest` so it is the date array that does not work.

Comment: @ScottCraner bingo. `?application.large(array(now,now+2,now+4),1)` confirms this. By all means, your answer! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between `Value2` property and the `Value` property is that the `Value2` property doesn't use the `Currency` and `Date` data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the `Double` data type. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value2-property-excel)

All you have to do is change the line

```
fltArr(items-3) = Cells(items, 6)
```

to

```
fltArr(items-3) = Cells(items, 6).Value2
```

Try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim Largest As Date

    For counter = 1 To 10
        Dim fltArr(0 To 9) As Variant
        Dim X As Variant

        For items = 3 To 12
            fltArr(items - 3) = Cells(items, 6).Value2
        Next

        X = fltArr

        Largest = Application.Large(X, counter)
        Debug.Print Largest
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: And with that one could skip the whole inner loop and just assign the values to the array directly: `X = Range(Cells(3, 6), Cells(12, 6)).Value2`

Comment: Agreed. I would always prefer assigning a range to an array directly :) The above was suggested keeping the original code intact :)

Answer (score 1):

Large does not like to work with Date Arrays.  If you declare the arrays as doubles it will return the values you want(Using your code):

```
Sub test()

    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 1 To 10

        Dim fltArr(0 To 9) As Double
        Dim X() As Double
        Dim Largest As Date

        For items = 3 To 12
        fltArr(items - 3) = Cells(items, 6)
        Next

        X = fltArr
        Largest = Application.Large(Range("F3:F12"), counter)
        Debug.print Largest

    Next
End Sub
```